# Package in Java

Tags: java

When do we actually use the package keyword? What does it mean?

Suppose I write the following code:

```
package masnun;    
public class masnun{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println("Hello maSnun!");
        }


}
```

What does this package thing do? I get a masnun.class file that doesn't run. I am new to Java. Can somebody please explain?

Thanks

Comment: The answers to this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088509/what-is-the-purpose-of-defining-a-package-in-java-file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I'm not a fan of these other answers, I'll write my own.

---

**Real World Examples:**

Think of a "package" as an easy way for a java class to reference another.

Let's say I have this big box in my attic. I have a calculator, compass, protractor, etc. I can label this box `MathTools`.

Another example would be taking all your pictures and putting them in the `Pictures` folder in your documents. From there, you could split them into `Spring Break 2009` or `[Insert Name Here]'s Party`.

How does this relate to Java? Well, let's look at the `java.util` package (you can reference this with `import java.util.*;`. You have ArrayLists, Strings, Random, etc. which are used in most Java programs (common "utilities", if you prefer). There are all neatly organized into the same package, so that programmers can easily reference them (`import java.util.*;`).

---

**Easy Application:**

Let's assume that we can find all the files to a small dice simulator in `C:/Program Files/Java Project/my/proj/` (it's likely that this file doesn't exist on your computer, but just pretend for a moment).

You have 3 files: `Main.java`, `Dice.java`, and `DiceRoller.java`. All of which are shown below:

---

"C:/ProgramFiles/Java Project/my/proj/main/`Main.java`":

```
package my.proj.main;

import my.proj.sims.Dice;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DiceRoller roller = new DiceRoller();
        roller.rollAndShow(4);
    }
}
```

"C:/ProgramFiles/Java Project/my/proj/sims/`Dice.java`":

```
package my.proj.sims;

import java.util.Random; // I used the Random class, but you can also use the Math class if you prefer (java.lang.Math)

public class Dice
{
    public Dice()
    {
    }

    public int roll()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();    
        return rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // Rolls a random number 1-6
    }
}
```

"C:/ProgramFiles/Java Project/my/proj/sims/`DiceRoller.java`":

```
package my.proj.sims;

public class DiceRoller
{ 
    public DiceRoller ()
    {
    }

    // Rolls and prints the result of 'n' number of rolls
    public void rollAndShow(int n)
    {
        Dice dice = new Dice();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(dice.roll()); // You should never use S.o.p in a method - it's bad practice, but it's easier this way if you don't yet understand the concept of objects
        }
    }
}
```

---

Things to notice:

- `Main.java` is packaged into `my.proj.main`
- `Dice.java` is packaged into `my.proj.sims`
- `Main.java` needs to import `my.proj.sims.Dice` in order to create a `Dice` object and use its methods because it's in a different package from `Dice.java`.
- `DiceRoller.java` does not need to import `my.proj.sims.Dice` because it is in the same package as `Dice.java` and the compiler will automatically associate the two.

---

`Import` is a command to load the functionality of a class into the current file. Look at `Dice.java`, for example. In order for it to create a `Random` object, which has the method `nextInt()`, it needs to import the Random class from the `java.util.*` package.

---

You might notice that some people would prefer to use `java.util.*` instead of `java.util.Random`, `java.util.ArrayList`, etc. What the `*` essentially means is any class within `java.util`. Running `import java.util.*` will import the Random, String, ArrayList, etc. classes.

Comment: Hey, great one! Have you finished eating? I'm waiting! :) Thanks for the time and efforts.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts and time. How do I compile it ?

Comment: @maSnun: Hey. Sorry, I ran out of time yesterday. Are you using an IDE (Eclipse, JCreator, NetBeans, etc.)? Have you installed the latest JDK (java development kit - http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp)?

Comment: @maSnun: Then there's a lot more to learn then what I can tell you in one post. Now that you understand packages, you can find plenty of java/command help pages, through Google.

Answer (score 4):

It's very likely for a software to have classes named Logger, Database, Connection, Table etc.
Packages separate the scope of these classes, so that you don't have issues with duplicate 
classnames.

A few examples:

- java.*
- org.apache.**
- com.yourcompany.yourproject.

If you wan't to use classes from a destinct package you need to import them .i.g.

```
import java.util.Date
```

or

```
import java.sql.Date
```

Answer (score 2):

It is such a way to organize your source files. A package contains multiple class file, a class file contains only a public class, a class contain multiple methods and variable.

Answer (score 2):

The package statement in Java is used to group several related classes. If you have classes that deal exclusively with Database interaction, it would be logical to put them all under

```
com.example.myapp.persistence
```

This also provides the benefice of name spacing, remember that at runtime part of a java class identity is its fully qualified name, that is, the class name preceded by its package name like in

```
com.example.myapp.persistence.UserDAO
```

When you're application grows to accommodate more than a couple of classes, it is both practical and a good practice to organize them in packages

Answer (score 1):

"Packages are nothing more than the way we organize files into different directories according to their functionality, usability as well as category they should belong to." from: http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html

Basically,  in your example, you are saying class masnun is package of package masnun.  So essentially in other classes you could reference this class by import masnun;  Which imports the class masnun which resides in masnun package.

Comment: Do I need to arrange the class file in a specific group? Perhaps like putting the masnun.class into a directory named masnun?

I still donn't get it. When I use that command - import masnun; , what really happens? Where does the JVM look for the package? Or does it look for the class?

I mean what will let me run that file by using the command "java masnun" ?

Comment: @maSnum: yes, the standard Java classloader looks for classes in a directory hierarchy that corresponds to the package hierarchy. Basically, import masnum.MyClass looks for a file MyClass.class in a directoy masnum in any of the classpath roots (which typically include the current directory).

Comment: I was going to try to answer this question, but: These are the very fundamentals of Java, it makes no sense for us to do a whole Java tutorial in the form of question-and-answer. You'd be better served reading (and working) a [Java tutorial](http://www.programmingtutorials.com/java.aspx) or two.

Comment: I know this is very fundamental and I did a lot of googling before I posted here. Didn't get the answer to my questions.

Answer (score -1):

In Layman term, Lets suppose that there are multiple department in a college like science , arts etc. Now each department has some employee. In terms of object there can be multiple Employee class so there is restriction in java that we can't put two class as same name .So programmer should make different packages to store different class with same name in application.