# Making jUnit output info and compile to /build folder

Tags: ant, junit

I have the following Ant buildfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<!-- the value of the default attr must be one of the targets. -->
<project name="Money" default="build-source" basedir=".">        
    <description>The Money project build file.</description>
    <property name="src" location="."/>
    <property name="build" location="build"/>
    <property name="junit" location="lib/junit-4.9b3.jar"/>

    <path id="_classpath">
        <pathelement path="${junit}"/>
        <pathelement path="${build}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="prepare">
        <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build-source" depends="prepare"
            description="compile the source ">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}">
            <classpath refid="_classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="build-source">
        <junit printsummary="on" showoutput="on">
            <test name="money.MoneyTest"/>
            <classpath refid="_classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
</project>
```

It's pretty basic - I'm just trying to get this thing to run properly. What I don't get is: 1) Why does it output the compiled files to a /build/money directory? I want the output directory to be just /build, given this directory structure for my files:

```
build/
build.xml
lib/
src/
test/
```

2) When there are tests that don't pass, it says "Test money.MoneyTest FAILED". I'd like it to output info about the failure, expected / actual values, line number, etc.

I can't figure this out by staring at the buildfile above.   Any advice?

Comment: PS. Those directories above (and build.xml) are all on new lines of course, so they are all on the same level

Comment: When posting to SO, if you indent code - or whatever - by 4 spaces it will appear formatted as you typed it.  You can use the curly brackets {} button in the Markdown editor bar to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

1. It outputs the compiled files under `build`, creating a directory structure that corresponds to the layout of your packages.

   Since you put your classes in the `money` package, the output will be under `build/money`. If you put your classes under a `org.example.foo` package, your output would be in the `build/org/example/foo` directory.

   To have your `.class` files in `build`, you would have to use the default package.

   **Edit**
   I assume your source files have a `package money;` declaration, as in:

   ```
   package money;

   public class MoneyTest {
   ...
   }
   ```
2. If you add a `<formatter>` element, detailed reports about test failures will be written to an output file (by default, named TEST-*name*). See also the [Ant Junit Task Documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).

   ```
   <junit printsummary="withOutAndErr" showoutput="on">
       <formatter type="plain"/>
       <test name="money.MoneyTest"/>
       <classpath refid="_classpath"/>
   </junit>
   ```

   I have not found a way to directly print the failed tests reports to standard output.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I still don't understand the 'money' package deal. I don't have a 'money' package - just a folder named Money with the above folder structure. You say to have my classes under build I have to use the default package, what is that package? Thanks.

Comment: The folder your .java files live in must match the `package` declaration at the top of the .java file. See edited answer. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088509/what-is-the-purpose-of-defining-a-package-in-java-file