# Which Java access modifier allows a member to be accessed only by the subclasses in other package?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I had to shorten the title a bit. Here's the full question:

In Java which access modifier allows a member to be accessed only by the subclasses in other package or any class within the package of that member's class?

I am thinking `protected` but my office mate says the answer is `private`.

Comment: Either your office mate is pulling your leg, or you are pulling ours.

Comment: @Marko - No leg pulling just some confusion. Which are you saying is the correct answer?

Comment: I suggest you try it. You will find out quickly enough.

Comment: Here's another good table for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Java which access modifier allows a member to be accessed only by the subclasses in other package or any class within the package of that member's class?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

see this might help..you ! this is the scope of all access modifiers in java.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visibility of the properties  of class for different access modifiers

——————————————————————————————————————

1) From the same class

```
      Public , Protected, Private and Default
```

2) From any class in same package

```
      Public, Protected and Default
```

3) From a subclass in same package

```
      Public, Protected and Default
```

4) From subclass outside the same package

```
      Public and Protected (by inheritance)
```

5) From any non-subclass or class outside the package

```
      Public only
```

Answer (score -1):

It can't be private because private member methods are accessible only within the same class.

protected does not mean that a member will be accessed only by a subclass it specifically means that the classes are accessible within a package.

Your question is either wrong or you missed something on the way of asking your doubt.

Please have a look at the following :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Ritz - thanks. I will go back and look at the details. The question was translated from Japanese so I think something was lost in translation :-(